# Deleting specific display setting created with xrandr

Tags: linux-mint, display, xrandr

I want to delete a display setting which I set up via `xrandr` to my Linux Mint distribution.

```
xrandr --rmmode 1368x768_60.00
```

gives me this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private 
resource denied)
Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  17 (RRDestroyMode)
Serial number of failed request:  32
Current serial number in output stream:  33
```

I also tried it with `sudo`  , which prints out the same error.

Besides that I also deleted my `monitors.xml` file, with no effect.

How can I properly delete my display setting `1368x768_60.00` ?

Comment: I think the problem come from : --rmmode name
              This removes a mode from the server if it is otherwise **unused**. Try to start on another mode.

Comment: @ctac_ you are right, that helped me solving the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As ctac_ already mentioned, the mode has to be unused. So I switched to another mode, used `xrandr --rmmode 1368x768_60.00` which nevertheless has thrown an error and still showed the mode in the display settings.

Rebooting after that helped, and the mode wasn't available anymore.

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
xrandr --delmode <output> <name>
```

for example:

```
xrandr --delmode HDMI-1 1368x768_60.00
```